# Atribuição de valores por jQuery não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um código javascript que preenche campos no formulário com dados "terceirizados", a maioria das atribuições está ok, o problema é em campos que consideramos "masked" e recebem somente números.

O código é o seguinte:

```
....
//Como a variável "input" é definida neste contexto
//Percorre todos os campos do formulário de origem da requisição
//e que "desejam" utilizar os dados da consulta. 
//O valor {id_formulario_origem) é substituído em tempo de execução...
jQuery('#{id_formulario_origem}').find("*[data-consulta-cnpj]").each(function () {
    utilizarDadosConsultaCNPJ(jQuery(this));
});
....
function utilizarDadosConsultaCNPJ(input)
{
....
var valor = htmlDecode(campo_correspondente.html()),
            numeros = valor.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            input.val(numeros);
```

- A variável campo_correspondente pega o valor do campo "terceirizado";
- A variável números aplica um pequeno regex e deixa apenas números;
- A variável input representa um objeto jQuery do input;

*Exemplos de valores obtidos por um console.log() destas variáveis:*

```
88.350-450 88350450 jQuery.fn.init[1]
```

Vamos trabalhar com o input de id "endereco-cep" neste exemplo, então segue o mais estranho:

```
input.val(numeros); //Não funciona
input.val(htmlDecode(campo_correspondente.html())); //Não funciona
input.val = numeros; //Não funciona
jQuery(input).val(numeros); //Não funciona
jQuery("#" + input.attr("id")).val(numeros); //Não funciona


var inputJS = document.getElementById(input.attr("id"));
inputJS.val = numeros; //Não funciona

jQuery("#endereco-cep").val(numeros); //FUNCIONA!
```

Alguém consegue me explicar o motivo de utilizar o id "digitado" diretamente no código funcionar e os demais não?

Talvez um detalhe importante, estes campos são "masked" e utilizamos o seguinte plugin de mask: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

**EDIT**

Utilizamos a framework Yii 2.0, portanto a declaração pode parecer um pouco incomum para alguns.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cep', [
    'addon' => [
        'append' => [
            'content' => Html::button('<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>', ['id' => ConsultaCEPWidget::ID_BOTAO_INPUT_CEP, 'class' => 'btn grey-mint', 'title' => 'Consulta CEP']),
            'asButton' => true
        ]
    ],
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'btn-hidden-ajax'
    ]
])->widget(MaskedInput::className(),
    [
        'mask' => '99999-999',
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'data' => [
                'consulta-cnpj' => 'cep', 'consulta-cnpj-tipo' => 'maskedNumeros',
                'consulta-cep' => 'cep',
                'consulta-cei' => 'cep', 'consulta-cei-tipo' => 'maskedNumeros',
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
?>
```

Resultado em HTML:

```
<div class="btn-hidden-ajax field-endereco-cep required has-success">
    <label class="control-label" for="endereco-cep">CEP</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="endereco-cep" class="form-control" name="Endereco[cep]"
                                    data-consulta-cnpj="cep" data-consulta-cnpj-tipo="maskedNumeros"
                                    data-consulta-cep="cep" data-consulta-cei="cep"
                                    data-consulta-cei-tipo="maskedNumeros"
                                    data-plugin-inputmask="inputmask_0bf71e59">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" id="botao-consulta-cep" class="btn grey-mint" title="Consulta CEP">
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript gerado do inputmask:

```
var inputmask_0bf71e59 = {"mask":"99999-999"};
jQuery("#endereco-cep").inputmask(inputmask_0bf71e59);
```

Comment: pode mostrar a declaração do `input`?

Comment: Rafael, você precisa ver qual o "tipo" desta variável `input`, ser for `dom` o método `.val()` não irá funcionar por que pertence ao jQuery.

Comment: @MarllonNasser Vou colocar na pergunta...

Comment: @devgaspa e ai, tudo certo? então... testei da seguinte forma agora... input.val = numeros; E retornou o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: input.val is not a function

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft como você cria esse `input.val()` ?

Comment: @devgaspa Vou adicionar na pergunta como a variável "input" é criada...

Comment: Fiz mais alguns testes e consegui resolver o problema tirando o regex para deixar somente números... *input.val(valor);* funcionou... por em quanto vou deixar dessa forma ;/ o que não entendo é que alguns dias atrás estava tudo funcionando perfeitamente...